# Something error in code?

Tags: makefile

There is showing an error in line 9, "missing Separator". but I am given space in place of tab. Where is Error?

```
#sudo apt-get install g++ binutils libc6-dev-i386
GCCPRAMS = -m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exception -fno-leading-underscore
ASPARAMS = --32
LDPARAMS = -melf_i386

objects = loader.o kernel.o

%.o: %.cpp
    gcc $(GCCPRAMS) -c -o $@ $<

loader.o: loader.s
    as $(ASPARAMS) -o $@ $<

mykernel.bin: linker.ld $(objects)
    ld $(LDPARAMS) -T $< -o $@ $(objects)

install: mykernel.bin
    sudo cp $< /boot/mykernel.bin

mykernel.iso: mykernel.bin
    mkdir iso
    mkdir iso/boot
    mkdir iso/boot/grub
    cp $< iso/boot/
    echo 'set timeout=0' > iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'set default=0' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'menuentry "My Operating System" {' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'multiboot /boot/mykernel.bin' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo 'boot' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
    echo '}' >> iso/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

1. When I run this in command shell by typing make showing an error, **makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.**. I removed the space in file "makefile" but still showing error
2. showing "-m32 -fno-use-cxa-atexit -fno-builtin -fno-rtti -fno-exception -fno-leading-underscore" is not a command. How to install it

Answer (score 0):

Does line 9 start with spaces instead of a tab character? You **must** use a tab to indent commands in rules.

Comment: it start with tab